# How come Python's dict doesn't have .iter()?

Tags: python

```
def complicated_dot(v, w):
        dot = 0
        for (v_i, w_i) in zip(v, w):
            for x in v_i.iter():
                if x in w_i:
                    dot += v_i[x] + w_i[x]
        return float(dot)
```

I'm getting an error that says:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

Comment: **DON'T** use `__iter__` directly as @yi_H suggests. Use `iter(v_i)` or just `for x in v_i`.

Comment: uhm I didn't want to suggest using it, just told it's name. actually both of those codes will call `__iter__`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[It has `iter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter). But you can just write

```
for x in v_i:
```

Answer (score 16):

Considering the following [`dict`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

You can just iterate over the keys like so:

```
>>> for k in d:
...     print(k, d[k])
... 
('a', 1)
('c', 3)
('b', 2)
```

This implicitly calls the special method [`__iter__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__), but remember:

> [Explicit is better than implicit.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

### Python 2.*x*

What would you expect the following to return?

```
>>> tuple(d.iter())
```

Too ambiguous, perhaps?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

That seems like a perfectly reasonable approach.

What if you wanted to iterate over just the *keys*?

```
>>> tuple(d.iterkeys())
('a', 'c', 'b')
```

Nice! And the *values*?

```
>>> tuple(d.itervalues())
(1, 3, 2)
```

How about the *keys and values* as pairs (tuples)?

```
>>> tuple(d.iteritems())
(('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2))
```

### Python 3.*x*

Things are [slightly different](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#dict), the objects returned by `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()` are [view objects](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). These can be used in much the same way, though:

```
>>> tuple(d.keys())
('a', 'c', 'b')
>>> tuple(d.values())
(1, 3, 2)
>>> tuple(d.items())
(('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2))
```

Answer (score 8):

```
v_i.itervalues()
```

You have [`iterkeys`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iterkeys), [`iteritems`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) and [`itervalues`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues). Choose one.